# Sunspot_rails gem not working for me in rails 3.1rc5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot-rails

When ever a perform a search query i get wrong number of arguments 0 of 1

my controller code is as follows

```
  def search
     @search = User.search do
       fulltext params(:search)
     end
     @friends = @search.results
  end
```

and my model is as follows

```
  searchable do
    text :name
  end
```

pls what am i getting wrong here or the gem does not support rails 3.1. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller should be like this:

```
def search
   @search = User.search do
     fulltext params(:search)
   end
   @friends = @search.results
end
```

The **params** variable is a hash and should be accessed as such, using **[]** not **()**.

Comment: Just to confirm - I'm having the exact same issue as the OP with my params being specified correctly with square brackets. Any help?

Comment: Nevermind - fixed my problem almost instantly (had a method in the model called search).